# SetForegroundWindow method sometimes does not hide start menu

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have a Windows form with no border that is set to maximized in order to make it look "fullscreen".  When I open my fullscreen form in my C# app I call the following code...

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
```

With the handle I get from the Windows forms api by calling...

```
        ScreenScrape.SetForegroundWindow(Handle.ToInt32());
```

When the "Shown" event is raised.

The only problem is sometimes I get the expected result (a fullscreen app with nothing in front of it) and sometimes I get this...

[image]

If i click anywhere on my Windows form and its embedded browser I see this...

Another developer suggested programmatically clicking at a known location Say 10,10 but that seems like a hack.  Any idea what might be happening here?

[image]

Comment: Have'nt you tried setting TopMost = true;  ?

Comment: In the Shown() event, try calling this.Activate(); this.BringToFront();